# Angular (4/5/6/7/8) Refactor subscribe within subscribe code

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8, subscribe

Hi I would like to simplify the following code. It's difficult to apply switchMap in the following situation because I'm using a forEach loop for the 2nd subscribe method. What is a better way of coding this out? Appreciate your help!

```
activities: Activity[];
notifications: any[] = [];

 this.profileService
  .listProfileActivities(this.authService.profileId)
  .subscribe({
    next: activities => {
      this.activities = activities.filter(
        activity =>
          activity.type === 'favorite' &&
          activity.to === this.authService.profileId
      );

      this.activities.forEach(activity => { // forEach loop is here
        const notification = {
          profile: null,
          profileId: '',
          imageId: '',
          name: '',
          timeago: new Date(),
        };
        this.profileService
          .readProfile(activity.from) // 2nd subscribe method dependent on forEach loop variable
          .subscribe(profile => { 
            notification.profile = profile;
            notification.profileId = profile.id;
            notification.imageId = profile.imageID;
            notification.name = profile.name;
            notification.timeago = new Date(activity.at);
          });
        this.notifications.push(notification);
      });
    },
  });
```

Comment: instead of subscribing at every stage, `pipe` your logic using [concatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) then apply `switchMap`

Comment: Looping and nested subscription make you app's performance so bad. You can use `concatmap`. But better you should find another solution based on your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way might be leveraging *pipable* operators, and flattening the `array` with `mergeAll`.

```
this.profileService
  .listProfileActivities(this.authService.profileId)
  .pipe(
    mergeAll(),
    filter(activity =>
        activity.type === 'favorite' &&
        activity.to === this.authService.profileId
    ),
    mergeMap(activity => 
        this.profileService.readProfile(activity.from)
                           .pipe(map(profile => ({ profile, activity })))
    ),
    map(result => ({
        profile: result.profile,
        profileId: result.profile.id,
        imageId: result.profile.imageID,
        name: result.profile.name,
        timeago: new Date(result.activity.at)
    }))
  ).subscribe({
    next: notification => this.notifications.push(notification)
  });
```